# Canvas does not recognize value of object literal

Tags: javascript, object, canvas, literals

I cannot figure out why this is not working. On the surface it would seem that the canvas functions will not accept an object value, but that doesn't seem right.

```
function draw() {
var ctx = document.getElementById('canvas1').getContext('2d');  
var c1 = {
    midX : 100,
    mixY : 100,
    lowX : 90,
    lowY : 120
};
console.log(c1);    // this logs the object
console.log(c1.midX);   // this logs value of midX

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(c1.midX,c1.midY);
ctx.lineTo(c1.lowX,c1.lowY);
//  ctx.moveTo(100,100);   // this works fine
//  ctx.lineTo(90,120);    // this works fine
ctx.stroke();
} 

window.onload = draw;
```

Comment: What does not work? What error do you get?

Comment: typo - `mixY` -> `midY`

Comment: @GregoryTippett clearly not using your console to check for errors. This typo would show up there

Comment: @charlietfl - not so clear. In fact I am just learning to use the console & debugger and was not able to find it after quite some time and experimentation. How about providing a demonstration of how you would find the above error?

Comment: @charlietfl passing `undefined` to these methods doesn't throw an error, it is just ignored. The console would only have helped if all the props were logged (inducing other potential typos)

Answer (score 1):

Because of the name of your properties

Inside c1, you have `midX` but `mixY` and not `midY`, so when you call `moveTo` you have an undefined.
Just update and be carefull with your naming

Comment: Thank you. Big sigh. I really thought I had combed this thoroughly for typos. They are sneaky!